# nodejs app can not run on port 80 using express

Tags: node.js, express

I am running the below code taken from express 3.0.3 node_modules/express/test.js:

```
 /**
  * Module dependencies.
  */

 var express = require('./')
 , app = express()

 console.log(express.json());
 app.use(express.favicon());
 app.use(express.logger('dev'));
 app.use(express.cookieParser('foobar'));
 app.use(express.session());

 app.get('/', function(req, res){
     res.send('hello');
 });

 app.listen(80);
 console.log('listening on 80');
```

Now if I start the node app with "sudo node test.js", the app starts fine and I am able to see the 80 port being listened on using netstat, however when I use browser on port 80, then I do not get any response. But I use any port other than 80, it works.

Can you please let me know what I am missing here?
Why I can not run node app on 80 using express?

With regards,
-M-

Comment: Is there any other server apache or tomcat etc running? if yes then close them.

Comment: Adding to @AmitGarg's comment, you can run `netstat -tlnp` to see what programs are listening on what ports.

Comment: There is no other process running on 80 port, I verified that already. When running node, it runs without any error on this port. But browser request on this port 80, does not return anything.

Comment: Just noticed that it does not work if I use localhost:80, but otherwise works for 127.0.0.1:80, though the netstat output is as below:                                                              `tcp4   0   0  *.80   *.*   LISTEN`